# posting to googleplus http server using nodejs module request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-plus

Im trying to get the google plus share count for a given url, i can make it work using jquery on the client side, but now im trying to do it on the server side using nodejs.

for example in jquery, i would use this:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ",
    data: [{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"http://www.test.com","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}],
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

I want to do the same thing using request module on nodejs:

```
request.post(
    'https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ',
    { form: [{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"http://www.paulgraham.com","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}] },
    function (error, response, body) {
         console.log(response.statusCode)
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

I can't seem to figure it out. i get `415` error.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: youre missing the whole post data, in your client side example you post data to an url with the query parameter "key", in your node example youre posting "key" to /rpc and no other data